# Typescript type with no more than 10 unique properties, or an entry-based equivalent tuple of length 0 - 10

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing some generic wrapper code over the Javascript AWS SDK. The SDK is pretty atrocious in some ways that I'd like to make a little bit less painful.

SQS allows passing in some message attributes (`MessageBodyAttributeMap`), which for the purposes of this question, we'll pretend is typed as `{ [key: string]: Buffer | Uint8Array | Blob | string }` (this is part of the sugar I'm hoping to add).

But, an unexpressed constraint here is that there can only be 10 properties in this message attribute object, and it does seem impossible to enforce a speific number of object properties in TypeScript. There is something that can enforce length, though, a tuple of entries that I could easily convert to an object at runtime:

```
type MessageValue = Buffer | Uint8Array | Blob | string
type Entry<
  TKey extends string,
  TValue extends MessageValue
> = TKey extends never
  ? never
  : TValue extends never
    ? never
    : [TKey, TValue]

type EntryTuple<
  TEntry1 extends Entry<string, MessageValue> = never
  TEntry2 extends Entry<string, MessageValue> = never
  // T3 - T9
  TEntry10 extends Entry<string, MessageValue> = never
> = [TEntry1, TEntry2, /* T3 - T9 */, TEntry10]
```

Theoretically, a concrete `DurableQueue` class accepting `TEntry1` - `TEntry10` generic type arguments could at construction time lock in a particular set of entries so the type system would enforce the `AttributeMap` type on both input and output messages. I'd be happy accepting an object but also an actual entry-set suitable for `Object.fromEntries()` and returning entries as well using `Object.toEntries()`.

But there are some serious problems.

1. Types can always be a union. As a tuple, there's no guarantee that each entry-key is a single string const.
2. Right now, I'm also struggling to figure out how to get each value to be a particular type so they don't vary per tuple entry.
3. `Object.toEntries()` has no guarantee about order of keys. Maybe I could solve that by my class accepting an entry-sorter callback and allowing the constructing caller to guarantee the sorter will match the output tuple type's order?
4. Uniqueness is going to be a problem. I might be able to use some clever recursive types to union all TEntry1 - TEntry10 keys together and ensure the input quantity matches the unioned (and deduplicated) key quantity.

How can I defer specification of my pseudo-`MessageBodyAttributeMap` to construction time through generic type arguments?

To try to make this more concrete, if I were to statically type my class so the below `queue()` class method had one exact `AttributeMap` definition (which method will call `SQS.sendMessage()`), it might look like this, where `TypeArguments` represents the unknown type parameters I'd need to use to achieve the goal:

```
class SqsQueue<TypeParameters> implements IDurableQueue<TypeParameters> {
  private readonly _sqs: SQS
  constructor<TypeParameters>(sqs: SQS) {
    this._sqs = sqs
  } 
  async queue(
    body: string,
    attributeMap: [
      ['attribute1', Uint8Array],
      ['attribute2', string],
      ['attribute3', Buffer]
    ] // the concrete type of up to 10 entries 
    // or an equivalent object with no more than 10 properties
    // that was actually specified by the new() call's type arguments
  ) {
    const result = await this._sqs.sendMessage({
      MessageAttributes: convertAttributeMapToSqsMessageAttributes(attributeMap),
      ...
    })
    ...
    return transformedResult
  }
}
```

That is, when we instantiation the above class:

```
const myQueue: IDurableQueue<...> =
  new SqsDurableQueue<
    [
      ['attribute1', Uint8Array],
      ['attribute2', string],
      ['attribute3', Buffer]
    ]
  >()
```

the type arguments would be in the form shown but would be required by the class's type parameter constraints to:

1. be a tuple between 0 and 10 items long
2. use unique string entry-keys
3. and guarantee each entry-value would be only one of `Buffer | Uint8Array | Blob | string`

I know this is a complicated question and it may be a long shot to ask. Perhaps after sleeping on it I'll have some inspiration (that does tend to happen sometimes). In the meantime, I'm stuck on how to practically allow creation of a `DurableQueue` class that in effect (if not actuality) lets me define an object of no more than 10 unique properties as described.

*My question seems pretty terrible; I'm definitely having trouble succinctly explaining what I'm trying to do. My apologies for that, and for any readers making it this far, I have much gratitude!*

P.S. I just thought of mixins, but have never actually used them successfully. I've only played with them here and there. Not sure how that would help solve things. I wonder if using a "template object" in a mixin factory function (to infer the `MessageAttributes` type from) could help create a type that would at least, at construction time, throw if the template object had more than 10 properties?

Comment: Consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9bzom) example. Argument with exactly 10 props is allowed, otherwise forbidden. Also, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/union-array)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I had already run across this prior art when playing with this earlier and saw many warnings about such conversions not being reliable. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I would not rely only on this solution. I believe you also need to use a typeguard `Object.keys(obj).length <=10`. Static typing will not allow you to use interface with more than 10 props and runtime solution will guard you.

Comment: [Equally atrocious implementation...](https://tsplay.dev/mp87bm)

Comment: @vera I know TypeScript will enough to read and understand that. I alwo know TypeScript well enough to shy away from it unless *absolutely* necessary. :) But impressive.